# How to remove vowels from an entered text with greater efficiency?

Tags: c

Basically, a school assignment.
I solved it, but it's too slow for them (the site that tests my code).
Keep in mind that I can only use `getchar` and `putchar` for any text related assignments as we only started learning C.
It's my first post, I apologize if I made any mistakes in this question.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(){
    char ch = getchar();

    while(ch != '\n'){

        ch = getchar();

        switch(ch){
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'O':
        case 'U':
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':continue;
        default: putchar(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: it should not be `char ch` but `int ch`, which is the type returned by `getchar` and also the type for `'A'` etc. Also `case 'u':continue;` should be `case 'u':break;`

Comment: Isn't `y` and `Y` part of the vowels ? Slow in what aspect, could you be more precise ?

Comment: If you have studied arrays, you could initialise array elements to indicate which are vowels. Then in the loop you only need, say, `if(vowel[ch] == 0) { putchar(ch);}`. But watch out for `EOF` which you can't use to index an array.

Comment: Note that if the input ends (`EOF`) without a newline — which can happen, even if the input is from a terminal — your code goes into an infinite loop.  Although it is conventional to use `break;` to terminate the actions in a `switch`, using `continue` in this program certainly works correctly (though `break;` would also work correctly).  It's a good idea to put `break;` (or `return;`, or `continue;` or — perish the thought — `goto`) after each action, even if it is the last at the moment.

Comment: shouldn't the second `ch=getchar()` be after the switch (with break, as said above), to not lose the first character entered?

Comment: @B.Go that is correct, in which case `continue` will not be right. Alternatively a single `getchar` with `while((c = getchar()) != '\n')`

Comment: Your code discards the first character input, regardless of what it is.  It also won't terminate if there's not a newline in the input.  Other than that, if you compile with optimization, it is likely as efficient as you can get, so I expect efficiency is not your problem.  If your automatic test is giving you a timeout, it is likely the infinite loop when there's no newline that is causing the problem.

Comment: There is nothing "slow" about the way you have coded it. The code is "wrong", but not "slow". Fix it given the comments above and re-submit. `getchar()` reads from a buffer of `BUFSIZ` (8192-bytes on LInux, 512-bytes on windows). Your code will optimize as good, or better, than any fancier approach.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing faster (using only `getchar` and `putchar`) that I can think of is:

```
int main() {
    int ch = getchar();
    while (ch != '\n') {

        if (ch>64)
        {
               if(ch <118)
               {
                    if (((4575140898685201 >> (ch-65)) & 1)==0){
                            putchar(ch);}
               }
        }
        ch = getchar();
    }
}
```

Try it with

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

it outputs

> BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz

I don't know if it is the purpose of the exercice or not but this reduces the check to only three exclusive `if`.

But if you use CLANG compiler in O3 optimization the compiler does exactly that for you: [GodBolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/p__Nah)
So when you say that it is too slow for "them", do you mean only by looking the code or once compiled ? Because if it is once compiled it should not be "too slow".

**Explanation**
maybe `((4575140898685201 >> (ch-65)) & 1)` is a little obscure.
‭4575140898685201 is a 64bits integer and looks like this in memory  00010000010000010001000100000000000100000100000100010001

As you can see the '1' are located at 0, 4, 8, 14, 20, 32, 36, 40, 46, 52.
If you add 65 to that serie you get 65, 69, 73, 79, 85, 97, 101, 105, 111, 117 which is ASCII for A, E, I, O, U, a, e, i, o, u.

‬The operator `i >> j` shifts `j` bits to the right of `i` so it is a vowel if jth bits is `1` hence the `& 1` or `& 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

If you understood this answer and liked it as an exercice you can try calculating which number to put in to also get rid of Y and y and put it in the comment (heads up [GodBolt with Y and y](https://www.godbolt.org/z/-jgbzt) won't help you, but the generated code is interesting to look at especially `ror    eax`, and it should end with `UL` because it can only be represented as a 64bits integer)!

Answer (score 2):

It is very strange that such a simple code is deemed too "slow", especially if `getchar` and `putchar` are mandatory.

If I do something like this with your program (creating a file without `\n` and redirecting it to your program):

```
echo -n "abc" > input.txt
./program < input.txt
```

I get an infinite loop. Maybe your website is reporting a timeout rather than slowness ? You need to use `EOF` rather than `\n` with `getchar`.

Here an example that you can try. I used `strchr` but the switch case is fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int ch;

    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
            break ;
        else if (!strchr("aeiouAEIOU", ch))
            putchar(ch);

    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I find it very strange too, the fact that such a simple code is too slow.. The checking works like this: I type in the code (copy/paste) and their program checks it for some 5 random examples and, basically I get a TLE. (Time limit exceeded) the program should be able to work under 1 second for it to be fast enough. Idk really. I cant really imagine the size of the texts they are using for testing if it takes more than one second, btw I will try your code in the morning, and thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing *"slow"* about the way you have coded it. The code is *"wrong"*, but not *"slow"*. `getchar()` reads from a buffer of `BUFSIZ` (8192-bytes on LInux, 512-bytes on windows). Your code will optimize as good, or better, than any fancier approach.

Your primary problems are, as noted in the comments, `ch` must be type `int` instead of `char`. The return of `getchar()`, e.g. `EOF` is type `int`. Next, you call `getchar()` twice before entering your `switch()` statement. To fix the problem with `getchar()` move the second `getchar()` below your `switch()` so it is called after the `switch()` is executed. You will need to change the default case in your `switch()` from `continue` to `break` to not skip the `getchar()` after the `switch()`. Finally, remove the test for `'\n'` (unless that is an assignment constraint). You want to `'\n'` to be output to preserve the "lines" of input instead of running it altogether.

What is *"good"* and *"fast"* about your code? You approach with a `switch()` statement with case-fallthrough for all vowels will optimize very very well producing lightning fast code. Make sure you specify an optimization level of `-O3` (gcc/clang) or `/Ox` (VS, `cl.exe`). That will tell the compiler to fully optimize your code for speed. (there are additional optimizations, but not important here). So your **approach** was really, really good! (you failed at its **implementation**)

Correcting the **implementation** your approach could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int ch = getchar();     /* read character */

    while (ch != EOF) {     /* check for EOF */

        switch (ch) {       /* switch w/fallthrough to default */
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u': break;        /* break, not continue */
            default: putchar(ch);   /* output char if not vowel */
        }
        ch = getchar();     /* read next char from file */
    }
}
```

(and no, `[Yy]` are NOT vowels)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/fleas.txt
My dog has fleas
My cat has none
Lucky cat
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getchar_skip-vowels < dat/fleas.txt
My dg hs fls
My ct hs nn
Lcky ct
```

Leave the *"magic-number"* programming to your compiler to provide through optimization, that is what compilers do. If you dump the above code to assembly to look at the actual assembly instructions with `-O3` (or `-Ofast`) optimization under gcc, you will see the compiler has optimized the assembly to check against the magic numbers, e.g. (with `-masm=intel` for Intel syntax) the relevant part of the code is reduced to:

```
    mov     rdi, QWORD PTR stdin[rip]
    push    rbx
    movabs  rbx, 4575140898685201
    call    _IO_getc
    cmp     eax, -1
    je      .L8
```

(in fact, that is essentially the entire code, the jump to `.L8` simply being the exit procedure on `EOF` and the comparison and loops being no more than 3 `mov`, and `cmp` and jump)

So don't think your approach was wrong, it was fine and *readable*, it was the implementation where you fell short. For that, there is nothing better than learning [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Always strive for a straight-forward and readable approach, and let the compiler apply the optimizations.

Comment: Sure. It was clear that you were thinking right, you just were not typing right `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make this faster is with a lookup table.  The main thing that makes this not the fastest possible is that the code devolves to a bunch of comparisons, something like:

```
if(ch == 'A') goto isvowel;
else if(ch == 'E') goto isvowel;
else if(ch == 'I') goto isvowel;
.
.
.
isvowel: putchar(ch);
```

but that's so inconsequential that in real life, who'd care?

But the way to make it faster is to use a a table:

```
int isvowel[] = {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Now you just need to change your letter to a number from 0 to 26.  First, if you look at the ASCII internals, you see that a lowercase letter differs from an uppercase letter by only a single letter.  So you can make something upper case always like this:

```
ch & 0xFFDF;
```

To convert to a number, you just subtract the value of the first letter:

```
(ch & 0xFFDF) - 'A'.
```

Then, to see if it is a value, you just test of the array at that position is `1`:

```
if(isvowel[(ch & 0xFFDF) - 'A')
```

Note that if `ch` is not a character, our math won't work, so we need to guard against that.

So the full code becomes something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(){
    char ch = 0;

    int isvowel[] = {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0};
    while(ch != '\n'){

        ch = getchar();

        unsigned int ord = (ch & 0xFFDF) - 'A';
        if( ord < 26 && isvowel[ord])
             putchar(ch);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

The reason this is (very slightly) faster (but not fastest possible) is that you are doing only two comparisons, and not ten.  If you look at the old version, internally, it's something like:

```
compare to 'A'
compare to 'E'
compare to 'I'
compare to 'O'
compare to 'U'
compare to 'a'
compare to 'e'
compare to 'i'
compare to 'o'
compare to 'u'
```

With the table, it becomes

```
and with 0xFFDF
subtract 'A'
compare with 26
dereference table
compare
```

So about half the operations.  But with modern processors, we're talking nanoseconds in either case, so I really wonder why this would come up in an intro assignment.

Note that this is exactly how standard library methods like [isalpha()](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/isalpha) are usually implemented.  For `isalpha()`, there is a 256 entry table with every value that is alphabetic in ASCII set to true, every value that is not set to false.  This makes these extremely fast, faster than my implementation here as they don't need to convert to upper case or check for out of bounds.

But I want to emphasize: **You should not worry about such inconsequential differences.**  This is the kind of thing you do after spending weeks with a profiler in production code, not in student assignments!.

**Addendum:**

If you are using gcc, you can generate ASM code with `gcc -S`.  This is useful for seeing the raw code a program compiles down to.  The switch in your original looks like this in ASM:

```
    movsbl  -5(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    subl    $65, %edx
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    movl    %edx, -16(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    je  LBB0_3
    jmp LBB0_7
LBB0_7:                                 ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax         ## 4-byte Reload
    subl    $69, %eax
    movl    %eax, -20(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    je  LBB0_3
    jmp LBB0_8
LBB0_8:                                 ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax         ## 4-byte Reload
    subl    $73, %eax
    movl    %eax, -24(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    je  LBB0_3
    jmp LBB0_9
LBB0_9:                                 ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax         ## 4-byte Reload
    subl    $79, %eax
    movl    %eax, -28(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    je  LBB0_3
    jmp LBB0_10
LBB0_10:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax         ## 4-byte Reload
    subl    $85, %eax
    movl    %eax, -32(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    je  LBB0_3
    jmp LBB0_11
LBB0_11:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax         ## 4-byte Reload
    subl    $97, %eax
    movl    %eax, -36(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    je  LBB0_3
    jmp LBB0_12
LBB0_12:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax         ## 4-byte Reload
    subl    $101, %eax
    movl    %eax, -40(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    je  LBB0_3
    jmp LBB0_13
LBB0_13:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax         ## 4-byte Reload
    subl    $105, %eax
    movl    %eax, -44(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    je  LBB0_3
    jmp LBB0_14
LBB0_14:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax         ## 4-byte Reload
    subl    $111, %eax
    movl    %eax, -48(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    je  LBB0_3
    jmp LBB0_15
LBB0_15:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax         ## 4-byte Reload
    subl    $117, %eax
    movl    %eax, -52(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    jne LBB0_4
    jmp LBB0_3
LBB0_3:                                 ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    jmp LBB0_1
LBB0_4:                                 ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
```

With the table, it looks like this:

```
    movsbl  -117(%rbp), %eax
    andl    $65503, %eax            ## imm = 0xFFDF
    subl    $65, %eax
    movl    %eax, -124(%rbp)
    cmpl    $26, -124(%rbp)
    jae LBB0_5
## %bb.3:                               ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -124(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    cmpl    $0, -112(%rbp,%rcx,4)
    je  LBB0_5
## %bb.4:                               ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
```